# Why Phoenix require all nested resource in the parameter, Using cast_assoc or put_assoc

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, nested-resources

The case is one_to_many and I want to insert and update necessity minimum nested resources at the same time.

According to https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3, `cast_assoc` require us to update/insert nested resource with all associations in the parameter. If we don't include all associations, cast_assoc invoke `:on_replace` action for the missing associations.

I think it’s OK to work with the form generated by Phoenix templates because form sends all association in the parameter every time. But if this function works with JS frameworks, I can send necessity minimum　associations which are changed on a web browser. In such a use case, may I repeat update in a transaction as well or do same as a template does?

I feel a little bit tricky for that behavior. And I feel it's better to add action explicitly into the parameter instead of `:on_replace`

What do you think about it?

Comment: This should be emailed to `Ecto` maillist, or like. As it is, it’s an offtopic here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that next if I have such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Phoenix requirement, it's an Ecto requirement. If Ecto does not have all of the information pertaining to your schema then it cannot reliably create an accurate changeset.

I'm not really understanding your specific question, but if you want to update the record without re-supplying associations, then create a separate changeset function that doesn't touch the association.

Comment: Yup. Exactly it's an Ecto matter. I imagine this requirement looks redundant and creating changeset based on receiving parameter and preloaded association seems intuitive. But Ecto keeps us from doing thins so I just wonder why Ecto make us include redundant information. OK I should do that, Thank you lukerollansさん！

Comment: It can seem redundant at first, but keep in mind that Elixir is a functional language and can't magically grab data from a source like, say, Rails does.

If you're generating a changeset for a record, Ecto needs to know what has changed in the association if you're using `cast_assoc`, which means supplying before _and_ after, even if they are identical. (ps. you don't need to use `cast_assoc` if you don't want to).

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I got it. I'll care about functional from now on. Thanks a bunch   :)